# Summarize using dplyr and shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I currently have an app setup where it lets the user input which variable they want to plot and visualize. I am running into an issue when I am trying to pass off the shiny input variable into summarize.

```
testData <- plotData %>% 
        summarize(means=mean(input$selectedMetric, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
        summarize(sd=sd(input$selectedMetric, na.rm=TRUE))
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Warning in mean.default(input$selectedMetric, na.rm = TRUE) :
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

How am I supposed to set it up so that it takes the mean and standard deviation of whatever selected column the user decides?

Comment: Please show the entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few things can go wrong here:

- You are not checking for `null` when using `input$selectedMetric`
- You improperly using `reactives`. You should access the reactives by using `()` at the end as they are functions that return something.

Below Im assuming that your `plotData` variable isn't a reactive and its a declared object

```
testData <- reactive({
  if(is.null(input$selectedMetric)){
    return()
  }
  plotData %>% 
    summarize(means=mean(input$selectedMetric, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
    summarize(sd=sd(input$selectedMetric, na.rm=TRUE))
})

testData()
```

You can access the summary, like so: `testData()`